# Sending email with mixed data from both form inputs and database data

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to send email of which one of the data is from database, i tried to look on some post here in stack-overflow but they were different;

I tried to send without the data from the database and it works fine,but after adding database fetch its not working

```
<?php
include 'include/connect.php';

if (isset($_POST['book2'])) {

    $id     = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['id']);
    $sql    = "SELECT room_price FROM room_details WHERE id='$id';";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

            $room_price = $row['room_price'];
            $email      = $_POST['email'];
            $room_type  = $_POST['room_type'];
            $checkin    = $_POST['checkin'];
            $checkout   = $_POST['checkout'];
            $adults     = $_POST['adults'];
            $children   = $_POST['children'];

            $mailTo  = "booking@johndoexxx.com";
            $headers = "Guest sent e-mail from: " . $email;
            $txt     = "New booking received, room for " . $adults . " adults and " . $children . " child / children, reservation starts on " . $checkin . " up to " . $checkout . " whereby " . $room_type . " room is selected, Please respond to the sender!";
            $heading = "New Booking!";

            mail($mailTo, $heading, $headers, $txt);
            header("Location: index.php?bookingsent");
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "Booking failed to process!, observe your inputs carefully!";
}

?>
```

was expecting it will fetch data from form and will send the data into the targeted email.

Comment: @Th3210n  did you try to keep all $_POST assignments out of the loop and prior to access to the db? Please use debugging info it will resolve the issue

Comment: Mulli let me try and see what will happen, that one i did not try

Comment: Mulli i tried to put out of the loop but still not working, am stuck here!

Comment: OK. Next you must know were it breaks: 1. Does it pass the if statement? 2. What value is returned from mail?

Comment: It's working now @Mulli